# Recompiled OCX is not initializing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, vb6, activex

I have been asked to maintain this legacy activeX written in VB6. I have identified a change I need to do with it. But once I recompile and register the activeX, the object wont load

the object is initialized as shown below

```
<OBJECT style="display:none;" ID="Utils" Name="Utils" CLASSID="CLSID:EF82C1E0-36D4-4BDE-8EEB-10C7105C3FAF"></OBJECT>
```

at a later stage, the object is referenced in script as shown below

```
if (typeof document.all.utils != "undefined" && document.all.utils != null)
```

here document.all.utils  is undefined :(

I have been digging this for few hours now and can't find anything useful. I tried going through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/941zhks9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, but that link does not address what should be done to ensure that the object is accessible

Can anyone help me what I need to

Comment: Did you break binary compatibility?  Is your LPK file out of date?  Are there any helpful symptoms (error messages, etc.)?

Comment: I don't have LPK file. How do i check the binary compatibility?

Comment: The first step is to look at the IDE's Project Properties' Component tab.  This is where you deal with compatibility.  But in the end it's all about GUID changes in the classes and type information and the COM interface versions.  Can you get a VB6 programmer to help you?

Comment: I hadnt changed the compatibility mode when I asked this question. but you are right the class guid got changed somehow. I am guessing that happened when i saved the project file from notepadd++. So this started working after I deleted the local copy and got latest copy. Thanks Bob77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Bob77, the problem was that my class guid got changed. apparently it got changed because I saved the .vbp file!!! not sure, how that happened.

the best way to verify the class guild will be to look in registry

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[yourComponent]\Clsid
```

NOTE: this will work only after you register the component

to resolve this, I simply deleted the folder that contained the project and checked out the latest from source control. once I had the latest code, it compiled with the same class guid

the following link will be very useful to anyone running into a similar problem

http://forums.asp.net/t/1547658.aspx?INTEROP+CLSID+changes+every+new+build+How+can+I+solve+it+as+application+asp+net+does+not+stop+when+new+DLL+is+registred+